# Use of logical address

Tags: memory, cpu

Why do CPUs need a virtual address(logical address) to access data from a physical address.

Suppose we have this command:

```
mov dl,1
```

Why does the operand of this command use the virtual address of the register dl and not its physical address?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/a/1351232/19943 long story short we use virtual memory for process separation and memory management rather than letting every program run amok in the same memory space and potentially overwrite each other.

Comment: Use of virtual memory is an option. The processor is booted with virtual memory turned off. Some processors do not have virtual memory capability.  In normal operation, every address used by the CPU corresponds to the physical memory location (unless there's a mapping performed external to the CPU by some other scheme). BTW your phrasing in your post is nonsensical: there is no such thing as "*the virtual address of the register dl*". Registers do not have "*virtual addresses*". Presumably you are referring to the contents of the register. Big difference.

Comment: Registers are by definition a collection of binary cells so by definition they must have both a physical and logical address.

Comment: @Volpina -- You repeatedly conflate "*logical*" and "*virtual*". Those two adjectives are not necessarily identical or interchangeable for all processor archetectures. E.G. the 8086 CPU has logical addresses, but no virtual addresses. Clarify your question by using consistent wording. BTW your example is not a "*command*" but an *instruction*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without the ability of virtualizing addresses, every single program written by every single programmer that ever existed, does exist, and will ever exist would have to agree on which program uses which addresses – otherwise, they would accidentally overwrite each other's data (or worse, *intentionally* corrupt or access other program's memory, for example a virus being able to read passwords). This includes programmers who are already dead and programmers who haven't been born yet.

Virtualizing addresses is much easier.

Of course, there is also the possibility to forbid accessing addresses altogether. Many modern programming platforms do this, e.g. the Java platform, the Common Language Infrastructure / .NET platform, the Web platform (i.e. ECMAScript), etc. In these systems, memory is managed by the platform and user code cannot directly access memory, it only gets access to opaque, unforgeable, unmodifiable pointers.

But really, this is just another form of memory virtualization.

Comment: Your answer makes no sense. You're ignoring all the computers (in the past as well as present) that do not use virtual memory, and still manage to execute multiple programs concurrently. Apparently you're unaware of the concept of program relocation. Hint: look up Linux w/o MMU (aka uClinux project).

Comment: Program relocation is just load-time address virtualization.